# in bash using sed replace 'oldstring' with 'newstring'

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, substitution

I have an extra credit assignment that's asking me to take 3 arguments to use to rid of someone's name on their assignment and replace it with mine.
1st argument is the file name
2nd argument is the "oldstring"
3rd argument is the "newstring"

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
oldname=$2
newname=$3
changed=`grep -R "$oldname" $file | sed -i "s/$2/$3/g" $file`
done
```

this is the file I'm searching through

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
printf("Assignment #3-4, Smarty McSmartypants, smarty@mcsmartypants.smart\n");
printf("%0.4f\n",cos(sqrt(atoi(argv[1]))/10.0f));'
```

I'll be replacing "Smarty McSmartypants" with "my name" which works perfectly fine but when I run it again to try to replace "smarty@mcsmartypants.smart\n" with "my@email" there's no changes. Can someone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: How do you think having its stdin come from `grep -R "$oldname" $file` is changing the behavior of `sed -i "s/$2/$3/g" $file`?

Comment: As for your direct question, though -- `sed` doesn't take literal strings, it takes *regexes*. Not the same thing. `\n` as a regex doesn't match `\n` as a literal.

Comment: Also? Quote your expansions, *including* the filename. `"$file"`, not `$file`; otherwise, filenames with spaces will be broken out into multiple arguments.

Comment: ...if you want to do literal string replacement, btw, there are good tools for the job, but `sed` isn't one of them. See BashFAQ #21 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021 for a comprehensive discussion.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` matches line-by-line, so you can't use it to replace newlines. It looks like you're trying to replace a literal `\` followed by an `n`, however, in which case you need to escape the `\` so that `sed` doesn't treat the `\n` as an escape sequence.

Compare:

```
$ echo 'foo\nbar' | sed 's/foo\n/fib/g'
foo\nbar

$ echo 'foo\nbar' | sed 's/foo\\n/fib/g'
fibbar
```